# Python's iter function - what happens when I change the underlying iterator between calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the iter function to allow me to resume processing my list at the point that I stopped.  As I understand it, iter affectively makes a list into a generator.

Say I iterate through folder names:

```
self.foldernames = load_a_list_of_folder_names_from_somewhere()

def some_func(self):
    for foldername in iter(self.foldernames):
        print(foldername)
        break

some_func()
#(prints first folder name)    

#and I decide that my list of foldernames is now out of date and reload it:
timeout = True
if timeout:
    self.foldernames = load_a_list_of_folder_names_from_somewhere()

#what happens when I run some_func again?
some_func()
# (will it start at the beginning of the list again?)  

# Is there some way to remember which position I was in the list and continue from there?
```

Comment: `iter` returns a generator.  If you want to keep using that generator, you'll need to save it to a variable.  I'm pretty sure that in this case, `iter` will remember the "old" list instead of being at the old position in the new list.  If that's not what you want, then you may have to manually keep track of the position you are at in the list.

Comment: Interesting - so iter makes a copy of the list and therefore if I changed the original list, then it would make no difference to the behaviour of the iter variable that I had set up? So that leads me to wonder how I update my list - do I need to determine of the list of modified and then re-specify the x = iter(some_list)?

Comment: Say you have a list `l = [1, 2, 3]`.  If you do `i = iter(l)`  `l = [4,5,6]` `list(g)`  you'll get `[1,2,3]` back.  If you instead do `i = iter(l)` `l[2] = `100` `list(g)` you'll get back `[1, 2, 100]`.  This has to do with the mutability of lists in Python.  When you reassign the value of the variable `l`, it creates a new object, but leaves the old one lying around so that things like `iter` can still reference it.  When you change a vlaue in `l`, then the variable still refers to the same object, so when `iter` sees the change in the object it is "watching"